# Standard practice to represent state of user configuration (checkboxes, select lists) for a single-page application?

Tags: javascript, configuration, single-page-application

The application I'm building will not initially have registered users.  It will be a single page application--i.e., no reloading or changing pages.  There will be a set of options in the form of html checkboxes, select menus, etc.  Given a particular configuration, a generated musical sound is played when the user clicks 'play'.  After the sound is played, the configurations should remain the same until it is altered by the user.

I'm pretty new to Javascript at this point. What is a computationally fast and clean way to represent the state of the various configuration inputs?  I could have a function that is called each time the user clicks 'play' that gets all the information for each config component from the DOM and returns a configuration object, which would then be used to make the sound.  But maybe that's not the best way since that involves getting everything from the DOM every time.  Would it be better for each input to have an onclick/onchange function that modifies its respective field in some global configuration object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should cache you settings in a browser cache. you can use [aplify.store](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/) or any other cache libraries. It depends on your SPA configuration.

Every time user changes settings, you can call web service to save them in a database and update local browser cache. Then you load your page initially, you should load user settings into your cache and access values from it.

if you use [breeze](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/introduction) for data queries, caching is built in.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out something like [Redux](http://redux.js.org) for this.

I can imagine the 'checkboxes, select menus, etc.' mapping to parts of the application state and the changes made by the user resulting in actions.

This would even extend to the 'play' button quite well I think.